# Optaplanner employee rostering

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

I have installed openshift version of Employee Roster demo. I am using Call center example from UI. In "Spot Roster" tab when i mark certain spots as unassigned and click on "Solve" button, I see Optaplanner starts optimizing and see score for soft and hard constraints. Even after it finishes optimizing what marked as unassigned still remain as unassigned. And i can see hard constraint score:0.  Why these spots are not assigned to Employees available?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that those unassigned shifts are already published (dark border)? Up to at least the current version (7.8.0) we don't support "non-disruptive replanning" yet in the optashift UI, which is the practice of resolving "employees calling in sick" etc, for already published dates, **with a little changes as possible**. OptaPlanner does support that, we just haven't integrated it yet in optashift.

So currently, only draft shift (= dotted border) are scheduled. Scroll to the right to see those.